# Access XELement with a variable

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

I want to switch from XPath to LINQ to XML

My XPath code looks like this:

```
s_veraenderterknoten = e.Node.Text
xn_Nodeveraendern = m_oxmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//" & s_veraenderterknoten & "")
```

How can i do this with LINQ to XML?

I tried this way

```
dim xn_Nodeveraendern as XElement = m_oxmldoc("bla").(s_veraenderterknoten)
```

but this doesn't work

----- extend informations:
xml expample: XML Informations :

```
<Node ID="01|37b36d32-f11f-4b00-ae34-fcf63fb7f6a2" Status="1" Index="1">
  <Bez Spra="ENG">test1 eng</Bez>
  <Bez Spra="DEU">test2 eng</Bez>
  <Files>
    <File Link="01\097C06E9EE4841E5B31811CFA91732B0_1.XML" FileTyp="FG" Index="0" Export_SeqID="01" sub="01\097C06E9EE4841E5B31811CFA91732B0_1.XML" XBAP="1">
      <Bez Spra="DEU">Scorecard test1 1</Bez>
      <Bez Spra="ENG">Scorecard test2 1</Bez>
    </File>
    <File Link="01\37B36D32F11F4B00AE34FCF63FB7F6A2.XLSX" FileTyp="FI" Index="1" Export_SeqID="01" sub="01\37B36D32F11F4B00AE34FCF63FB7F6A2.XLSX" XBAP="0">
      <Bez Spra="DEU">A -C test1</Bez>
      <Bez Spra="ENG">A-C test2</Bez>
    </File>
  </Files>
</Node>
<Node ID="01|4eeca9d3-379d-40f5-868c-9aad1a9ed327" Status="1" Index="2">
  <Bez Spra="ENG">Production test 1</Bez>
  <Bez Spra="DEU">Produktion test 2</Bez>
  <Files>
    <File Link="01\4B9A6942C90F4FFC9804C63F792E0938.XLSX" FileTyp="FI" Index="0" Export_SeqID="01" sub="01\4B9A6942C90F4FFC9804C63F792E0938.XLSX" XBAP="0">
      <Bez Spra="DEU">Kennzahlen test 1</Bez>
      <Bez Spra="ENG">Key test 2</Bez>
    </File>
  </Files>
</Node>
```

The use case:
The user sees the informations in a gridview, now he can select any XML node:
"e.Node.Text" has the information about the selected node. Now i want to select the node in my XML to edit/ add new information and so on.

Comment: Could you expand your question with XML example and what you want to get from it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I don't know wheter it is the best way or not, but it seems to work with this code :

```
xn_Nodeveraendern = From var In m_oxmldoc.Descendants Where var.Name = s_veraenderterknoten
```